# Why is my question about nightshifts off-topic?

Tags: discussion

Could somebody please explain to me, why [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/185376/135123) is considered to be off-topic?

Some commenters demand more information, assuming the question has some tax or contractual context. It doesn't. Is there a requirement for questions on 'The workplace' to have this kind of context? I just want to make a list of my worktime and my overtime. That is all.

The fact that I came out positive reputation wise, although my question has a total rating of -4 at the time of writing *this* question, shows to me that not everybody shares the opinion that it was a bad question.

---

**EDIT:** From the answers and comments so far I get that there doesn't seem to be a strong consensus, although some seem to lean towards the starting day. I even anticipated this possibility in my question. Thus, although an unpleasent experience, I've learned something.

What I still don't understand is why my question received so much hate. I still think it is a good question.

Suppose for a moment that there *was* a strong consensus on which day to choose, that might have even made it into law in some countries. And this consensus would make it very weird and confusing if I were to choose the other day. Would my question then have been on-topic?

I'm still supprised, that there doesn't seem to be a strong consensus to answer my question. Nightshift have been around for some time, I would've expected that people would handle this consistently. And if my question wouldn't have been closed so fast and more people would've been allowed to through in their two cents, maybe a stronger consensus would've emerged.

So, what is the lesson to learn here? If I can't be sure that there is a very specific, generally accepted answer to my question, then it is off-topic?

Comment: It appears that you got the only answer you need: nightshifts are counted as part of the day on which they begin. Without providing any other context, what more are you looking for? "Is this codified by law? Are there regulations?" - are legal questions. "Or can everybody handle this as they please?" - is a company-specific question.

Comment: "nightshifts are counted as part of the day on which they begin." I'm not so sure. Seems to be a weak consensus so far. But it would've been an acceptable answer, if it was a little bit more substantiated.

Comment: Are legal questions strongly concerned with the workplace off-topic here?

Comment: "Nightshift have been around for some time, I would've expected that people would handle this consistently." We have no idea what "handle" means. I've worked night shifts and I've never had to deal with whatever problem you are having.

Comment: Just read the original question again. It defines very precisely, what I mean by "handle". And the fact that this question never occured to you makes it off-topic?

Comment: @user1785730 Your inability to articulate some sort of context makes it off topic. You said you want to make a table. That's about as much information that we get. We don't know for what purpose this table is made, who it is going to seen by, what they are going to do with the data, etc. If it's just for your personal use, do whatever you want.

Comment: @user1785730 And no, the question is meaningless to me. You may as well have asked, "What colour is Saturday?".

Comment: I've made a [new question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/185433/135123) offering all the context and background I have. Hopefully you'll be able to answer it now.

Answer (score 4):

*Not that it matters, but as I write this, your question has 2 upvotes and 7 downvotes.*

Answers need to be justified in some way. Hopefully with logic, or convention, or some other rationale. To be able to be justified, questions need sufficient context.

You have indicated there is no other context. You just have a personal need to list what day. We can accept that. However, there is no means for us to evaluate answers on merit, because there is no criteria other than whatever criteria is in your head.

So all answers, and their votes become meaningless. A bad answer becomes just a valid as a good answer.

If there is indeed no criteria that makes a good answer, then you may as well do whatever you want.

If there is no workplace-related criteria, your question becomes off-topic. Your question may as well be about tracking your TV-watching binges, restroom visits, late-night fast food runs, or some other arbitrary thing.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't follow you there. How exactly did my question make you think of restroom visits?

Comment: @user1785730 Your question may as well have been.